# Angular: tell ng-template its context

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-template

I quite often use ng-templates in my application to later include them in the *ngTemplateOutlet and pass them the context. However when I define the template itself, it doesn't know the interface the context will have, so say this:

```
<ng-template #willUseLater
             let-item
             let-index="index">
    {{index}} — {{item}}
</ng-template>
```

Gives me error like `ng: The template context does not defined a member called 'index'`.

Is there any way to tell ng-template what context it is going to have when it is used later one?

Comment: What exactly gives you that error? I just included your template and had no errors.

Comment: I donot see any errors though https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inxrny?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I believe this error message is produced by Angular CLI, probably it is not used in stackblitz. Added a tag for CLI to the question.